# libGDX: Hanging rope knotted with some pivot

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to make a hanging rope having some object at it lower end in libGDX,
Rope should be like [hanging rope in Box2D](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/10/05/basic-box2d-rope/)

I have done a lot of research, libGDX has its [ropeJoint](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/joints/RopeJoint.html) method but how to use it to make a rope?

Please help, It will be a great favor.

Comment: RopeJoint is not a physical representation of rope. It's rope-like constraint which enforces maximum distance. That is not what are you looking for

Comment: @kassak than what should I do to make a hanging rope, can you help please?

Comment: as in your link, you should create set of rectangles, connected with simple rotating joints. I haven't seen tutorials on that subject, using libGDX.

Answer (score 0):

I've started with the answer to a similar question
[libGDX: Hanging Rope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433047/libgdx-hanging-rope?answertab=active#tab-top)

and added some code to it to add some missing code and fix some problem in anchor, I think the following code is a suitable to the target proble:

```
    BodyDef ropeStartDef = new BodyDef();
    int EACH_RING_DISTANCE = 10
    ropeStartDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
    ropeStartDef.position.set(m_camera.viewportWidth/2,m_camera.viewportHeight );
    Body ropStartBody = m_world.createBody(ropeStartDef);
    PolygonShape ropeStartShape = new PolygonShape();
    ropeStartShape.setAsBox(5, 5);
    ropStartBody.createFixture(ropeStartShape, 0);
    ropeStartShape.dispose();
    //----------------------------
    RevoluteJointDef jd = new RevoluteJointDef();
    Body prevBody = ropStartBody;
    int angle = -90;
    Vector2 position = ropeStartDef.position;
    BodyDef previousbodyDefinition= ropeStartDef;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
            bd.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
            bd.angle = angle-MathUtils.PI/2;
            bd.position.set(position.x + i*MathUtils.cos(angle)*EACH_RING_DISTANCE, 
                            position.y + i*MathUtils.sin(angle)*EACH_RING_DISTANCE);
            Body body = m_world.createBody(bd);
            FixtureDef eachRingFD;
            eachRingFD = new FixtureDef();
            CircleShape chainCircleshape =new CircleShape();
            chainCircleshape.setRadius(4);
            eachRingFD.density = 2;
            eachRingFD.shape =chainCircleshape;
            body.createFixture(eachRingFD);

            Vector2 anchor = new Vector2(bd.position.x - MathUtils.cos(angle)*EACH_RING_DISTANCE/2f, 
                                         bd.position.y - MathUtils.sin(angle)*EACH_RING_DISTANCE/2f);
            jd.initialize(prevBody, body, anchor);
            //-----------------------added based on http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/10/05/basic-box2d-rope/
                RevoluteJointDef joint = new RevoluteJointDef();
                joint.initialize(prevBody, body, anchor);
                m_world.createJoint(joint);

            //------------------------end of added
            prevBody = body;
            previousbodyDefinition = bd;
        }
```